# What is the best way to get text? getText() is not returning the link text in google.co.in

Tags: selenium-webdriver

What is the best way to get text ? getText() is not returning the link text in google.co.in
I am trying to get the below text 
हिन्दी বাংলা తెలుగు मराठी தமிழ் ગુજરાતી ಕನ್ನಡ മലയാളം ਪੰਜਾਬੀ
For this i wrote the script also,but i get the output like ????.
I don't know why it happens.
can anyone suggest me to get the text.
Below is my script

```
public class LanguageLinks {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");

List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='addlang']/a"));
    System.out.println(links.size());

        for(int i=0;i<links.size();i++){
        System.out.println(links.get(i).getText());
        }

    }

}
```

Edit note : Added code block to include complete code.

Answer (score 4):

This is nothing to do with Selenium but mismatch in character encoding in Eclipse side. Please apply the following settings:

Go to : **Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace** . In **Text file encoding** section: Select **Other** radio, Select **UTF-8** from combo -> Click **OK** button.

After above settings is applied, please re execute the code again. You should see proper texts displayed on the screen.

Comment: can we use any locale for this, to convert any text to UTF-8. As i searched and found out the only way is to parse it as UTF-8, can we  do anything in java with it?

Comment: That will not help @VigneshParamasivam. Because the string itself is in UTF-8 format but Eclipse have different character encoding format set and is unable to recognize.

Comment: Thank U Mr.mfsi_sitamj.I got the output.I am new to the software.I follow the steps what u send and re execute the code i got the output what i want.Thank u

Comment: Glad to be of help! Please accept the correct answer if you feel that helped you addressing the issue.